# How to display different value than MatOption selected Value (i'm using MatSelect in Blazor)

Tags: blazor, mat-select

How to display different value than MatOption selected Value (i'm using MatSelect in Blazor).

for Eg:

```
<MatSelect id="dc_Origin" Label="Origin" @bind-Value="@originCodeEmptyString">
   @foreach (var item in GetMasterData.Value.MasterDataResult.ServiceAirports)
   {
    <MatOptionString Value="@item.AirportCode" @onclick='()=> OriginFlight_OnChange(item.AirportCode)' data-loading-text="" >
          <div class="CustomTypeahead">
          <p>
              <span>@item.CityName</span>
              <span>@item.AirportCode</span>
          </p>
          <label>@item.AirportName</label>
         </div>
    </MatOptionString>
    }
  </MatSelect>
```

Default value is showing as :  "Delhi DEL AirportName",

**I want to display like :** "AirportName (DEL)"

Comment: Can't you just rearrange the span and label format to match what you want?

Comment: No, we can't do this things. Because,  within the dropdown option should show as "CityName CityCode AirlineName" but after selection it should show like "CityName (CityCode)"